# full_profile permissions for LinkedIn API

Tags: linkedin-api

We need access to partner API program for accessing full_profile permissions to get the skills data. the form in the website is not working to submit the partner program.

Comment: I have the same problem now and now way to reach out to them or ask about the permissions that would work or the partner program they have. This is not good. I thought they would have some kind of support team to answer these questions. The site say the partner program is not accepting applications. now way to now if this means indefinitely or when to expect any news?